# ->getArrayResult(); alters the value in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, encryption

I have a Bundle that en-/decrypts values in my database: [Ambta Bundle](https://github.com/ambta/DoctrineEncryptBundle)

Usually the Bundle decrypts all values "automatically" when fetching them.
However, if you get them via `->getArrayResult();` the result is still decrypted. I want to decrypt it manually afterwards.

**Query**

```
public function allActiveArray(){

    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT r, a, z FROM AppBundle:Rating r JOIN r.assignment a JOIN a.zip z WHERE r.published = :publish ORDER BY r.createdAt DESC'
        )
        ->setParameter('publish',true)
        ->getArrayResult();
}
```

I decrypt it like that:

```
$dspName = $this->get('ambta_doctrine_encrypt.encryptor')->decrypt($rating['displayName']);
```

This works somehow, but the returned `$decrypt` has some gibberish data appended to the decrypted value:

**displayName in DB**

`3Ytmz0qWhj0Lk/New2hqCEJGXaATD+6PafxYuxuprCo=<ENC>`

**Expected Output of $dspName**

`T. H.`

**Actual Output of $dspName**

`T. H.[9�gם��)�9/P�p�^��R/��`

Something gets added, but why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what is see, `3Ytmz0qWhj0Lk/New2hqCEJGXaATD+6PafxYuxuprCo=<ENC>`, encrypted data is base64 encoded and then `<ENC>` is appended to it (`=` is used to complement, end, base64).
Indeed it looks like the [bundle add those](https://github.com/ambta/DoctrineEncryptBundle/blob/master/Subscribers/DoctrineEncryptSubscriber.php#L276) to identify encrypted data. Try removing those characters first.

Comment: Wow, I thought that's what `$currentPropValue = $this->encryptor->decrypt(substr($getInformation, 0, -5));` actually does... I removed it now manually and it worked!!!